# User unable to delete folder / files "File in use by another user" Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, share, directory

I am administering a standalone Windows 2003 Terminal Server with no domain membership. Occasionally (about once a week or so) a user will attempt to delete a sub-folder in a Shared folder and gets denied with "File in use by another user". I tried checking the shared folder snap-in and that folder is not open. She has full control and is the owner of the folder as well. I even checked in "Effective permissions" for some of the folders / files she cant delete and she truly has full control. I am able to delete the folder as Administrator with no problem. Another odd thing, she can delete the files IN the folder most of the time (this issue happens on both folders and files in the share). Sometimes merely waiting a day or two will allow her to delete the folder or files. I am curious as to why she gets the message that it is in use as creator/owner with full control yet I don't get it simply as a member of the Admin group. If anyone out there has any ideas I'd love to hear them! THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool I use for such occasions is [unlocker](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/), which will allow the files/folders to be deleted. Of course that doesn't answer the question of why the permissions appear to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best approach, but sometimes is helpful to use procmon

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552.aspx

And a lot of other tools from sysinternals.

Comment: I have procmon and procexp ready to go for next time this happens, thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping that someone had a similar issue.